# Grouping values ​from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Good Morning !
I have the following array

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'disciplina_id' => int 3
      public 'nota' => int 4
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'id' => int 2
      public 'disciplina_id' => int 1
      public 'nota' => int 8
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'id' => int 3
      public 'disciplina_id' => int 3
      public 'nota' => int 9
```

I would like to "add" items that have the same value in the "discipline_id" column
since a course can have 1 or N notes, whenever it adds the fields, a notaX field is created to have the new note. ex: note,note1,note2,note3...

how can i do this? honestly I am well curled, I thought about using the methods (array_map, filter) but I have already lost more than 2 days in this problem.

could someone explain the logic to me?

Comment: Good morning. I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. So you want to search through the array for a specific 'disciplina_id' and add a value (noteX) the objects that were found?

Comment: So in my case the student may have a grade or not, what I really need is to gather the data by the index of the discipline_id column.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple issue for SQL query - group by column, if you can -  try to change it.
in PHP I would be make array where key its values of discipline_id and nota => array of nota values. Like:

```
$result = [];
        
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $disciplina_id = $data[$i]['disciplina_id'];
    $result[$disciplina_id][] = $data[$i]['nota'];     
}
```

And when you use json_decode(), you can add flag and get array instead object

```
$data = json_decode($data_json, true);
```